# Adding class to h tag or not?

Tags: css

Which one of these is better performance wise?

```
<div class="tag"><h1></h1></div>

.tag h1 {
    css;
}
```

or:

```
<div class="tag"><h1 class="someclass"></h1></div>

.someclass {
    css;
}
```

Which one load/render page faster?

Comment: 1) `h1` inside a `span` is invalid. 2) Test it. 3) The difference will be so minuscule as to be unmeasurable, and this should not be your primary criterion.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Aside from that, there is no "better", it entirely depends on the use case. Regarding speed: That is micro optimization par excellence. There is really no need to think about that.

Comment: Ok thanks. So if I change span to div, which one is better?

Comment: Are you even listening/reading to us?

Comment: You need to make the decision based on a number of factors such as: are you going to apply the same styles to other elements? do you need a higher specificity? *So if I change span to div, which one is better?* it's not that it is better, it's just valid. You see, heading tags are block-level and span is an inline element so it is semantically incorrect to wrap block-levels inside inline elements.

Comment: Just two quick thoughts: 1) I suspect that parsing invalid HTML is less efficient because the browser has to apply fixes before being able to build the DOM tree 2) If performance is your one and only concern, simply remove the class entirely

Comment: From my experience, it's better to avoid styling tags, because you are forcing conventions you might later regret. Tags are semantic to your *content* while classes are semantic to *style*. Keep those two separated and your life will be a lot easier :)

Answer (score 0):

As @deceze mentioned in the comments *"The difference will be so minuscule as to be unmeasurable, and this should not be your primary criterion."*.

But in reality, browsers match the selectors from right to left, meaning that in the first case (`.tag h1`) the browser will first fetch all the `h1` and then go up the DOM to see if they have any parents matching `.tag`.

In the second case (`.someclass`) the Browser will just fetch all the elements matching `.someclass`.

Since class selectors are supposed to be faster that tag selectors, I suppose that the second case is the fastest.

[Here is an interesting reading about this.](http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/)